# Convert collections.Counter to json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this collections.Counter

```
counter_obj
Counter({('A', 'B'): 170,
         ('C', 'D'): 650})
```

Trying to convert the keys which are in tuple format to string than use json.dumps function to convert in to json

```
dict = {str(k):v for k,v in counter_obj.items()}
json1 = json.dumps(dict)
```

when I print json i get this `\`. Where are the backward slashes coming from how to remove them and get a neat json format?

```
'{"(\'A\', \'B\')": 170, "(\'C\', \'D\')": 650}'
```

Comment: The slashes are for escaping, to keep the special characters (the `'`, in this case), so that if you were to load the same dictionary you just dumped, it would remain as a string, and not try to be parsed as a tuple

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not there. They are displayed because you get the representation of the json string and not its string version.

Demo:

```
>>> json1
'{"(\'A\', \'B\')": 170, "(\'C\', \'D\')": 650}'
>>> print(repr(json1))
'{"(\'A\', \'B\')": 170, "(\'C\', \'D\')": 650}'
>>> print(json1)
{"('A', 'B')": 170, "('C', 'D')": 650}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be because each element of your tuple is a string, and you're converting the whole tuple into a string

I myself am not too familiar with the json.dumps function, but could you not leave the key as a tuple when passing it to dict?

Comment: json dumps will only be taking key as strings it won't take tuple

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at what `str(('A', 'B'))` produces, because that will have backslashes to preserve the single quotes